# QML FileDialog Assertion failed

Tags: qtquickcontrols

I'm trying to use the FileDialog. but when I browse at the second time
I got a crash with information is

> "Gtk: Error assertion failed: (cancellable == data->button_data->cancellable)"

How do I address this problem?

Comment: Yes, you do it right!

Answer (score 1):

Qt5 can uses native file dialog from your desktop environment. There is some bug in a connection between Qt and GTK.
Looks like the same as
https://github.com/tkashkin/GameHub/issues/76